# Typescript-Typing not working for union and generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

So i was hoping to get the type for someConst.getFilterList.
The args in the function are inferred as any and there is no strong typing.

```
type SomeObj = { a: string, b: string };

type FlWithGetFilterListSub<T> = {
    origList?: never,
    getFilterList: getFilterFunc<T, ReadonlyArray<T>>,
} | {
    origList: SomeObj[],
    getFilterList: getFilterFunc<T, ReadonlyArray<SomeObj>>,
};

type FlWithGetFilterList<T> = { listProp: Array<T>, } & FlWithGetFilterListSub<T>;

type getFilterFunc<T, K> = (args: { fullList: K, text: string }) => ReadonlyArray<T>;

const someConst: FlWithGetFilterList<string> = {
    listProp: ['Some String Array'],
    getFilterList: (args) => { const { } = args; return [] },
};
```

Any Help On the same would be highly appreciated.
Thanks Regards.

Comment: What are you expecting the type to be? Given that there are two *different* possible types that a `combine<T>` could be, there are two (likely unrelated) types that `getFilterList` could have, so the compiler is picking the narrowest supertype, which I presume is `any`. What do you want the type to be?

Comment: What's `SectionListProps`?

Comment: Ok So i have edited my code, seems to be much cleaner now. My Apoligies. any ways i was expecting args.fullList to be Array<string> in this case and in case the consumer provides origList as a property i was expecting args.FullList to be an Array<SomeObj>.

Comment: ok seems much cleaner now.